# std::atomic as a value of std::map

Tags: c++11, dictionary, visual-studio-2012, gcc, atomic

I want to use atomic variable in a map. I am using Visual Studio 2012 (msvc-11) and gcc 4.7. I have defined a type:

```
typedef std::map<uint64_t, std::atomic<int64_t>> value_map_t;
```

In msvc-11, lines

```
value_map_t map;
map[1] = 0;
```

produce error:

> error C2248: `std::atomic<__int64>::atomic` : cannot access private member declared in class `std::atomic<__int64>`

Same happens with gcc 4.7 ([see here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J3cJEjnIygLWnkhl))

> error: use of deleted function `std::atomic<long int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long int>&)`

However, in Visual Studio 2013 (msvc-12) and beyond, as well as in gcc 4.8 and newer, it works fine.

See for yourself [gcc 4.8](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dtUmDoNDzrbFpc79) and [Visual Studio 2013+](http://rextester.com/JSDT80884)

What can I do in msvc-11 / gcc 4.7 to make it work ?

Comment: `std::atomic` is a C++11 feature, you probably should not expect these things to work very well unless you are willing to use a compiler offering robust support for C++11. Both gcc 4.7 and msvc-11 were pretty spotty in this regard.

Comment: Does this work in 2021?

Comment: Link to gcc 4.8 version is stale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to Visual C++ compilers, but I'm guessing the following  might work. Use an indirection, utilizing a map to (smart) pointers of `atomic`s:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <map>
#include <memory>


using atomic_ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<int64_t>>;
typedef std::map<uint64_t, atomic_ptr_t> value_map_t;


int main()
{
    value_map_t map;
    map[1] = atomic_ptr_t(new std::atomic<int64_t>(0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does work. It would be nice, however, to avoid extra new() at every insert for efficiency, as well as .get() for extraction. I wonder how new compilers work around it?

Comment: @VladimirShutow I completely agree with you. Again, I don't have access to this compiler. Sorry.

Comment: In case you want to test it, there is online gcc 4.7.3 compiler, I mentioned in the question http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J3cJEjnIygLWnkhl
, but thank you for this solution already.

Comment: The problem seems to be that such compilers did not yet implement enough of C++11, such as [this change](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), which allowed `map::operator[]` to *only* default-construct the mapped item, without requiring any copy/move constructors.

Answer (score 2):

With a hint from @Yam Marcovic I found how to do it in Visual Studio 2012:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::atomic<int64_t> value_t;
typedef std::map<uint64_t, value_t> atomic_map_t;

int main()
{
    int64_t in = 5;

    atomic_map_t map;
    map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
            std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple(in));

    auto it = map.find(1);
    int64_t out =  it->second.load(); 

    return 0;
}
```